# Add border to table cells

Tags: itext

I am attempting to add a border to my tr cells using ITextSharp.

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TR, HtmlTags.BORDER, "grey");
```

This is not working I also tried normal css style

```
css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TR, HtmlTags.BORDER, "1px solid grey");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Well at least good enough for now.

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.TR, HtmlTags.BORDER, "1");
```